python: heatmap with categorical color and continuous transparency
I want to make a heatmap in python (seaborn, matplotlib, etc) with two dimensions of information. I have a categorical value I want to assign to color, and a continuous variable (i.e. between 0-100 or 0-1) I want to assign to transparency, so each box has its own color and transparency (or intensity).
for example:
colors = pd.DataFrame([['b','g','r'],['black','orange','purple'],['r','yellow','white']])
transparency = pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.9,0.1,0.2],[0.1,0.6,0.3]])

how can I make a heatmap from this data such that the top left box is blue in color and 10% transparency (or 10% opaqueness, whichever), and so on?
The best idea I have so far is to turn the colors into integer values, add those to the transparency values, and then make a custom colormap where each integer has a different color, ranging from white to the color in between the integer values. That sounds complicated to make and I'm hoping there's a built-in way to do this.
Any ideas?

You could draw individual rectangles, giving each a specific color and transparency:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Patch
import pandas as pd

colors = pd.DataFrame([['b', 'g', 'r'], ['black', 'orange', 'purple'], ['r', 'yellow', 'white']])
transparency = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.9, 0.1, 0.2], [0.1, 0.6, 0.3]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, (color_col, transp_col) in enumerate(zip(colors.columns, transparency.columns)):
    for j, (color, transp) in enumerate(zip(colors[color_col], transparency[transp_col])):
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((i - 0.5, j - 0.5), 1, 1,
                               facecolor=color, alpha=transp, edgecolor='none', lw=0))

ax.invert_yaxis()  # start at the top
ax.autoscale(enable=True, tight=True)  # recalculate axis limits
ax.set_xticks(range(len(colors.columns)), colors.columns)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(colors.index)), colors.index)
plt.show()



For a custom color grid, you could use imshow.
The input is an array of shape (3, 3, 4): an image/grid with R/G/B/A values (Red/Green/Blue/Alpha ie transparency). The first two dimensions (3, 3) define the rows and columns of the grid.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

# Define the transparency and the colors
tr = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.9,0.1,0.2],[0.1,0.6,0.3]])
color_cells = pd.DataFrame([['b','g','r'], ['black','orange','purple'], ['r','yellow','white']])
# Convert the color names to RGB values
color_cells = color_cells.applymap(lambda c: colors.to_rgb(c)).to_numpy()

# On the 3rd dimension the first 3 levels are for R/G/B and the 4th for transparency
# Start by filling in the RGB values for each cell of RGB[:, :, 0 to 2]
mygrid = a = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3, 4))
for i in range(color_cells.shape[0]):
    for j in range(color_cells.shape[1]):
        for k in range(3): 
            mygrid[i, j, k] = color_cells[i, j][k]

# Finish by filling with the transparency in RGB[:, :, 3]
tr = np.expand_dims(tr, axis=0) # need to add a third dimension
mygrid[:,:,3] = tr

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3)) 
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(mygrid)


